# Ionic Framework3 missing main.css

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im creating starter template with 
`ionic start projname`
then ofc `cd ./projname` and `ionic serve`
And I got tabs template, but without main.css.
What I'm doing wrong and how can I resolve this?

[image]

UPD:
ionic dont want to compile styles

`ionic info`:
[image]

Maybe something wrong with my package.json?

```
{
  "name": "recepies",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Try deleting `www` folder of project and then run `ionic serve`.

Comment: not working, `ionic serve` creating everything except styles.

Comment: add output of `ionic info` and `ionic serve`

Comment: added ionic info to description

Comment: `'./build/main.css',` is there in `src/service-worker.js`?

Comment: yes, in self.toolbox.precache

Comment: Try doing `npm install`.

Comment: of course I tried, this not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug, that ate my day =/
Now solved.

"Upgrade back to the latest version of app-scripts"

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12442

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugins will be listed in:
**config.xml**.

Here is the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) for the ionic cli and here is the [Github project](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts) where source code for the scripts that are configured in your package.json reside.

Your **package.json** has a **scripts:** section:

```
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
```

According to [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm), you can invoke them with '**npm run clean**','**npm run build**', or `**npm run ionic:build**'. Try those. I hope that will delete and rebuild the **www/build** folder for you so it contains the **main.ss** that you see the errors for in your Chrome console.

If you still have problems, please post content of your **index.html**, maybe there is something missing that generates the CSS off the Sass files.
Do you for example have this in yours?

```
 <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
 <script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

If all else fails try `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",` in the devDependencies of your **package.json**, or some other version that doesn't conflict.
It seems to be broken on and off with various releases for some reason.

Comment: this plugins need to run  or build app on platform.
Ionic docs clearly tells `ionic start ....` then in dir `ionic serve` thats all.
With this should be created all files for web view.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/
there no word about this "statements" just few console commands -start and - serve thats all

Comment: and main.css should be created when I run `ionic serve`

Comment: your advice about to deploy to live or emulator, I need just webview.

Comment: NO! I opened console and create project via `ionic start`

Comment: when I run `ionic serve` and changing scss files, app reloading but main.scss not appears

Comment: try changing "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7" in  devDependencies of your package.json or some other version and please comment if this fixes it.

Comment: I'm watching this issue already https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12441#issuecomment-317187290

Comment: @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v6.11.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.10 is my setup. That works

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2:
browserslist@2.2.2 fixes the bug. Just upgrade it (`npm install browserlist@2.2.2`) or delete node_modules folder and re-run `npm install`.

UPDATE:
As Alicelf says, downgrading app-scripts isn't enought.
The problem is in browserslist@2.2.1 (pull request is waiting for merge the fix), then downgrading it to 2.2.0 fixed the vendor.js and the main.css problems.

```
npm install browserslist@2.2.0 --save-dev
```

> It's because an issue with the app-scripts version and dependencies.
>
> Downgrade it to v1.3.7 fixed the problem to me.
>
> `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@1.3.7 --save-dev`
>
> You could see the issue here:
>   https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12441 (closed)
>
> and here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12442

Comment: please, read all comments, before posting. Im already watching this issues and this causes new issue with 'vendor.js'