# How to create main.css in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in ionic. 
I am tring to create new my test ionic app.
I created ionic project using command

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
ionic start gallery
```

and run the app.
But it couldn't build main.css.

I want to know why the compile tool doesn't work.
so how can i fix it?

Please help me

this is the console

```
GET http://localhost:8100/build/main.css 
core.es5.js:3046 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
util.js:60 Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
cordovaWarn @ util.js:60
checkAvailability @ plugin.js:23
callCordovaPlugin @ plugin.js:107
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:226
value @ decorators.js:132
(anonymous) @ app.component.ts:18
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
onInvoke @ core.es5.js:4149
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
r.run @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4140
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
o @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
util.js:60 Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
cordovaWarn @ util.js:60
checkAvailability @ plugin.js:23
callCordovaPlugin @ plugin.js:107
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:226
value @ decorators.js:132
(anonymous) @ app.component.ts:19
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
onInvoke @ core.es5.js:4149
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
r.run @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4140
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
o @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
ion-dev.js?v=2.0.2:120 Dev server logger closed
11livereload.js?snipver=1:74 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
exports.Connector.Connector.connect @ livereload.js?snipver=1:74
(anonymous) @ livereload.js?snipver=1:55
(anonymous) @ livereload.js?snipver=1:1152
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
n @ polyfills.js:2
livereload.js?snipver=1:74 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And this is the screenshot when i run the app.

http://prntscr.com/fyxmcd

Comment: Try running  `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@2.0.2 --save-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today was a bug with app-scripts

[Ionic Framework3 missing main.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254103/ionic-framework3-missing-main-css/#answer-45257253)

This issue was solved a hour ago:

"Upgrade back to the latest version of app-scripts"

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12442

So, in general - just try to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug that has been fixed. Run

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@2.0.2 --save-dev
```

If still getting this error then delete `node module` folder and run

```
npm install
```